# grep count and saving matches different, why?

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I have two different Linux computers, one running a recent Debian and one a recent Ubuntu, and on both I try to match and save data from a large file (>6GB) using grep on command line in a terminal.

However, although the grep counts are the same, the exports are different. I am trying to understand why and if there is maybe a hidden setting in grep set somewhere which causes the Ubuntu computer to miss the so many matches (in both cases grep was installed using apt-get from the default repo and I am using the same file). Debian is returning results as expected.

Debian:

```
wc -l file
returns "33742301 file"

grep -i "pattern" -c file
returns "410882"

grep -i "pattern" file > new_file
wc -l new_file
returns "410882 new_file"
```

Ubuntu:

```
wc -l file
returns "33742301 file"

grep -i "pattern" -c file
returns "410882"

grep -i "pattern" file > new_file
wc -l new_file
returns "3911 new_file"
```

So why the difference with Ubuntu, especially since Ubuntu finds its roots from Debian?

I have tried this with many different text files over the last 1,5 years and there is always a significant difference between the Debian output and the Ubuntu output.

Comment: Just a guess, are any aliases defined for grep? You can check it with `alias grep` (assuming you use bash).

Comment: Show a sample of the lines that are reported by Debian but not Ubuntu, possibly with a `xxd`.

Comment: Maybe your locale is different - try running `locale`,

Comment: @reallife, try `grep --text -i "pattern" file > new_file`

Comment: @Heinrich aliases was not the issue. Thanks though :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell also locale was not the issue, both computers were using the same locale. Thanks though :)

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov this seemed to be the issue indeed. For some reason, some of the text was seen as binary and stopped at this point. Seemed that the grep versions were different from the repo, and as such it was not reproducing the same results on the two machines. Easiest way to solve this for the future is indeed forcing to using --text or -a. So `grep -a -i "pattern" file > new_file`. Thanks for the assist! Also @choroba :)

Answer (score 0):

Grep may interpret large file as binary. Try to use `--text` option in order to force text mode:

```
grep --text -i "pattern" file > new_file
```